# Рекуррентные нейронные сети в Keras и Tansorflow

Tags: нейронные-сети

Возможно я не совсем понимаю структуру рекуррентной нейронной сети, которую строит Keras. Пример с одним рекуррентным слоем понятен, есть слой который повторяется n раз. Вопросы возникают, когда появляется 2 рекуррентный слой. Находится ли этот 2 слой в одной и той же итерации что и первый рекуррентный слой или же сначала отрабатывается первый слой со своим количеством итерации а потом второй слой со своим количеством итерации? Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

При обучении сети все слои обновляются в одной итерации (эпохе).